# how to Switching from one bottomnavigationitem to another in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation, bottom-navigation-bar

im using bottom navigation for my app. in this i need to move one bottomnavigationitem to another while clicking the button.In this below image, Home is first screen here i'm having a button by clicking this move next bottomnavigation screen

Home -> Business &
Home -> School

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77035157/21590733

Comment: thanks vivek . from here how i move to business screen when i click 'Move to business' @VivekChib

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using pageView and PageController.

Custom Page:

```
class CustomPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final Color color;
  final String buttonText;

  const CustomPage({
    super.key,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.color,
    required this.buttonText,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: color,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(buttonText),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main Page:

```
class StackOverFlow extends StatefulWidget {
  const StackOverFlow({super.key});

  @override
  State<StackOverFlow> createState() => _StackOverFlowState();
}

class _StackOverFlowState extends State<StackOverFlow> {
  final PageController controller = PageController();

  int kSelectedPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: PageView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: controller, //page controller
        onPageChanged: (index){
          setState(() {
            kSelectedPage = index;
          });
        },
        children: [
          CustomPage(
            onPressed: (){
              controller.jumpToPage(1);
            },
            color: Colors.green,
            buttonText: "Jump to Business Page",
          ),
          CustomPage(
            onPressed: (){
              controller.jumpToPage(2);
            },
            color: Colors.yellow,
            buttonText: "Jump to School Page",
          ),
          CustomPage(
            onPressed: (){
              controller.jumpToPage(0);
            },
            color: Colors.cyan,
            buttonText: "Jump to Home Page",
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: kSelectedPage,
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            kSelectedPage = index;
          });
          controller.jumpToPage(index);
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home),label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.business),label: "Business"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school),label: "School"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge and understanding, this is what you've been looking for. It's a bottom navigation bar linked with their respective page (The page has buttons). So, the bottom navigation changes using the bottom tab & also using their page. I did optimization, the whole source code in under 100 lines. Feel free to provide acknowledgement in the comment section.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(title: "My App", home: HomePage());
  }
}

List<int> indexesList = <int>[0, 1, 2];
List<IconData> iconsList = <IconData>[Icons.home, Icons.business, Icons.school];
List<String> stringsList = <String>["Home", "Business", "School"];

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        items: List<BottomNavigationBarItem>.generate(
          indexesList.length,
          (int index) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(iconsList[index]),
            label: stringsList[index],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: indexChange,
      ),
      body: TabPage(index: currentIndex, callBack: indexChange),
    );
  }

  void indexChange(int value) {
    currentIndex = value;
    setState(() {});
    return;
  }
}

class TabPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabPage({required this.index, required this.callBack, super.key});
  final int index;
  final Function(int) callBack;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          if (index == 0)
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[buttom(1), buttom(2)],
            )
          else if (index == 1)
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[buttom(0), buttom(2)],
            )
          else if (index == 2)
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[buttom(0), buttom(1)],
            )
          else
            const SizedBox(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buttom(int toIndexindex) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => callBack(indexesList[toIndexindex]),
      child: Text("Navigate to ${stringsList[toIndexindex]}"),
    );
  }
}
```